# how to open multiple connections on multiple servers in the same ssms instance using batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a lot of sql server 2008 servers with many databases on each server.
I usually forget which database is on which server.
I want to create a batch file named after the name of the database that opens a connection to this database in the currently opened SSMS instance and not in a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution than creating a batch file to handle my problem.
I've registered all my database servers in the Registered Servers window under one Server Group and exported it to a file.
When I need to connect to an instance of them in the Object Explorer I just double-click the instance in the Registered Servers window.
When I need to write some sql code to be executed on an instance of them, I create a new Sql Server Scripts project, add my connections to the project and add sql files to write and save my daily scripts.